# Ansible not escaping windows path first argument

Tags: ansible

I have playbook with windows path name in the extra arguments. first argument not escaping the drive letter and slash.

```
ansible-playbook d.yaml  --extra-vars "ainstalldir=c:\\test stagedir=D:\packages outdir=d:\output\log"

TASK [print inpurt arguments] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "installdir=c:\test, stragedir=D:\\packages, outdir=d:\\output\\log"
}
```

installdir prints as `c:\test`, I expect it should print as `c:\\test`

Here is my playbook.

```
---
- name: test command line arguments
  connection: local
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    installdir: "{{ ainstalldir }}"
    stagedir: "{{ stagedir }}"
    outdir: "{{ outdir }}"

  tasks:
  - name: print inpurt arguments
    debug:
      msg="installdir={{ installdir }}, stragedir={{ stagedir }}, outdir={{ outdir }}"
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> installdir prints as `c:\test`, I expect it should print as `c:\\test`

`installdir` contains: `c` `:` <kbd>tab</kbd> `e` `s` `t`.

<kbd>tab</kbd> is replaced with `\t` in the `debug` module output and in effect you see `c:\test` on the screen.

Other characters starting with backslash in your example (`\p`, `\o`, `\l`) do not have special meaning, so they are treated as two character strings; but you'd observe the same phenomenon with `\n` (and other [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)).

---

1. Don't use `debug` module to debug things concerned with data, it processes strings to make them printable.

   Instead, use `copy` with `content` parameter and check the output in a file:

   ```
   - copy:
       content: |-
         installdir={{ installdir }}
         stragedir={{ stagedir }}
         outdir={{ outdir }}
       dest: ./result.txt
   ```

   (remember you could/should use `hexdump` to verify what's really inside).
2. Use:

   ```
   ansible-playbook d.yaml --extra-vars "ainstalldir=c:\\\test stagedir=D:\\\packages outdir=d:\\\output\\\log"
   ```

   or

   ```
   ansible-playbook d.yaml --extra-vars 'ainstalldir=c:\\test stagedir=D:\\packages outdir=d:\\output\\log'
   ```

   Backslashes in double- and single quotes are interpreted differently by shell (see for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398646/133107)).