# Ansible play book external parameter getting converted to unicode

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a playbook with few external parameters. One of those is a path in a windows server. When the directory name starts with letter 'a' it gets converted to "\u0007" character.

My sample is as below,

```
---

- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - debug: var=test_var
```

When I run it as below,

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_many samples/commandlinevars.yaml -e "test_var=D:\appli"
```

The output is as below,

```
PLAY [windows] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ABD665.testserver.com] => {
    "port_offset": "D:\u0007ppli"
}
```

If I run it without "" then the output is as below,

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ABD665.testserver.com] => {
    "port_offset": "D:appli"
}
```

For a folder name starting with any other letter I get no errors. Strange it is only for letter 'a' or 'A'. Any idea how to overcome this issue?

I went through the answer to [Ansible not escaping windows path first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239165/ansible-not-escaping-windows-path-first-argument), which is quite similar to my question. But when I go in to the exact point, my question hasn't been answered here.

In fact what I want is to pass the path D:\appli to the play-book.

Just to test the behavior of all 26 lower case characters, I ran the same play book in a loop and got the result as below ( I just took only the required line),

```
d:\atest
    "test_path": "d:\u0007test"
d:\btest
    "test_path": "d:\btest"
d:\ctest
    "test_path": "d:\\ctest"
d:\dtest
    "test_path": "d:\\dtest"
d:\etest
    "test_path": "d:\\etest"
d:\ftest
    "test_path": "d:\ftest"
d:\gtest
    "test_path": "d:\\gtest"
d:\htest
    "test_path": "d:\\htest"
d:\itest
    "test_path": "d:\\itest"
d:\jtest
    "test_path": "d:\\jtest"
d:\ktest
    "test_path": "d:\\ktest"
d:\ltest
    "test_path": "d:\\ltest"
d:\mtest
    "test_path": "d:\\mtest"
d:\ntest
    "test_path": "d:\ntest"
d:\otest
    "test_path": "d:\\otest"
d:\ptest
    "test_path": "d:\\ptest"
d:\qtest
    "test_path": "d:\\qtest"
d:\rtest
    "test_path": "d:\rtest"
d:\stest
    "test_path": "d:\\stest"
d:\ttest
    "test_path": "d:\ttest"
d:\utest
    "test_path": "d:\\utest"
d:\vtest
    "test_path": "d:\u000btest"
d:\wtest
    "test_path": "d:\\wtest"
d:\xtest
    "test_path": "d:\\xtest"
d:\ytest
    "test_path": "d:\\ytest"
d:\ztest
    "test_path": "d:\\ztest"
```

After this I realized even 'v' has the same behavior.

Finally I ran the same play book with different combinations as below just as a verification, and yet to find any answer.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_many samples/commandlinevars.yaml -e "test_var=D:\\appli"

ansible-playbook -i hosts_many samples/commandlinevars.yaml -e 'test_var=D:\\appli'

ansible-playbook -i hosts_many samples/commandlinevars.yaml -e 'test_var=D:\appli'

ansible-playbook -i hosts_many samples/commandlinevars.yaml -e "test_var=D:\\\appli"
```

Comment: @techraf, The characters 'a' and 'v' seems behaving differently. Can you please test the same.

Comment: Nope. They are behaving the same. \a is a bell ring. You need to turn your speaker on.

Comment: Yes. I know. But How can I give a path starting with 'a' as an external parameter. I dont want to it to be d:\\appli I want it to be d:\appli

Comment: Please read the answer under the duplicate target in full.